# Show that $2x + 1$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_4[x]$ and find a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2} [x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

> Show that $2x + 1$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_4[x]$. Then, for any prime $p$, find a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}[x]$ that is not a constant polynomial.

For the first part, $2x+1$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_4[x]$, since $(2x+1)(2x+1)=4x^2+4x+1=1$.My problem is in the second part. I have tried to use the freshman's dream theorem whit the expression $px+1$, but I have come to nothing. I think a hint would be enough. Thank you

Comment: What Freshman’s Dream?

Comment: @Thomas Andrews $(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p$

Comment: As usual to two part questions like this where the first is a concrete case, the hint is in the first case :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$(px-1)(px+1)=p^2x^2-1=-1$ which is a unit

Comment: The conclusion that $-1$ is a unit, is it because $\text{gcd}(p^2,p^2-1)=1$?

Comment: Easier approach is $-1(-1)=1$ so it is invertible have an inverse

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

You can use the fact that in a ring $R$ for a nilpotent element $r$ and a unit $u$ the sum

$r+u$ is again a unit. (Can you prove it?)

So it is enough to prove that $px$ is nilpotent (that means there is a  positive integer $n$ with $(px)^n=0$) in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}[x]$.

Comment: I think I follow. For instance, if $u=1$, then $(1+r)(1-r^2-r^3+\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}r^{n-1})=1$ and $(px)^2=0$, right?

Comment: Yes.  I suspect a typo in your multiplication, as the sign alternates. Step by step you could prove the stated result as follows: First prove that the multiple of a unit and a nilpotent element is again nilpotent. Now prove that the sum of a nilpotent element with 1 is again a unit (this is done as you did it), and now you can prove more generaly that the sum of a nilpotent element with a unit is again a unit. Of course for your statement you would only need the special case. Every step is easy to prove.

Answer (score 2):

The first part is actually a hint for the second. Notice that if $p=2$ then $px+1$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}[x]$ so it makes sense to try and generalize this. Now notice that
$$(px+1)(px+1)^{p-1} = (px+1)^p = \sum_{k=0}^p \binom{p}{k}p^kx^k = 1$$
so $px+1$ is indeed a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$.

Comment: Why $(px+1)^p=p^px^p+1$? Is char$\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}=p$?

Comment: @Hopmaths Yeah. And then you apply freshman's dream.

Comment: I thought that the characteristic of the ring in this case was the additive order of $1$. Why not in this case?

Comment: I'm a little confused. We're talking about rings. Also, these rings are not even integral domains. Could you clarify this please?

Comment: @Hopmaths I have edited my answer. If there is any doubt let me know.

Comment: $\Bbb Z_{p^2}[x]$ does **not** have characteristic $p$, its characteristic is $p^2$ and Freshman's dream doesn't hold anymore: $(1+1)^4\ne 1^4+1^4$ and $(1+1)^2\ne1^2+1^2$ in $\Bbb Z_4$. However in this case it is still true that $(px+1)^p=1$ because every term in the binomial expansion except the $1$ has two factors of $p$ in it

Comment: @leoli1 Fixed! Thanks for pointing out.